# How can I create another state inside Redux that contains two reducers to update the state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm creating a movie app using React/Redux that allows the user to choose a movie by clicking on a button (buy a ticket ) that takes the user to another page to choose the quantity of the ticket and add to the cart his purchase.

The idea is when the user clicks on the button add to card, I want two things to happen one is that the quantity should be updated in the badge cart in the navBar and also add this the movie to the bag if the user wants to checkout.

How can I create a state called cart in reducers to update the quantity and to add the movie into that cart when I click on add to a cart?

What do you think?

<-- Action types -->

```
export const ActionsTypes = {
     SET_MOVIES : "SET_MOVIES",
     GET_MOVIE : "GET_MOVIE", 
     REMOVE_MOVIE : "REMOVE_MOVIE",
     QUANTITY: "QUANTITY",
 }
```

<-- Quantity action-->

```
export const MovieQuantity = () => {
    return {
        type : ActionsTypes.QUANTITY
    }
}
```

<-- Reducers -->

```
const initialState = {
    movies: [],
};

//Movies Reducers
export const setMoviesReducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionsTypes.SET_MOVIES:
            return {...state, movies: action.payload }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

// single Movies Reducers
export const GetMovieDetailsReducers = (state={}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionsTypes.GET_MOVIE : 
            return {...state, ...action.payload}
        case ActionsTypes.REMOVE_MOVIE : 
            return {};
        default : 
            return state
    }
    
}

export const movieQuantityReducers = (state = 0 , action) => {
        switch(action.type) {
            case ActionsTypes.QUANTITY: 
               return state + 1;
            default :  
               return state;
        }
}
```

<-- Movie Details add to cart component -->

```
const MovieDetails = () => {
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1) 
    const singleMovie = useSelector((state)=> state.movie);
    const quantityBag = useSelector((state)=> state.quantity);
    const {title, poster_path, overview} = singleMovie;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    let {movieId} = useParams();

    
    // Handle Click Quantity
    const handleQuantity = (type) => {
        if(type === "dec") {
            quantity > 1 && setQuantity(quantity - 1)
        } else {
            setQuantity(quantity + 1)
        }
    }

    // add to cart Handler
    const CartHandler = () => {
        dispatch(MovieQuantity(quantityBag)) // the quantity is just incrementing
    }


    // Get a single Product & Remove product
    useEffect(()=> {
        try {
            const getSingleMovie = async () => {
                const request = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=&&&&&`);
                const response = await request.data;
                dispatch(getMovie(response))
            }

            getSingleMovie();

        } catch(error) {
            console.log(`ERROR : ${error}`)
        }

        //Clean up
        return () => {
            dispatch(removeMovie());
        }
            
    }, [movieId])


    return (
        <section className="movieDetails_container">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="img-container">
                    <img src={`${ImgPath}` + poster_path} alt={title}/>
                </div>

                <div className="info-container">
                    <h1>{title}</h1>
                    <p>{overview}</p>
                    <div className="quantity-container">
                        <Remove className="quantity-icon" onClick={()=> handleQuantity("dec")}/>
                        <span className="amount">{quantity}</span>
                        <Add className="quantity-icon" onClick={()=> handleQuantity("incr")}/>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn-add" onClick={()=> CartHandler()}>Add To Cart</button>
                </div>
                
            </div> 
        </section>
    )
}

export default MovieDetails
```

<-- navBar componenet -->

```
const Navbar = () => {
    const quantityBag = useSelector((state)=> state.quantity);
    return (
        <nav className="navBar-section">
            <Link to="/">
                <h1 className="logo">映画館</h1>
            </Link>

            <Badge badgeContent={quantityBag} color="primary">
                 <LocalMall className="icon-bag" />
            </Badge>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd model the state differently. From what you're describing, the following would work nicely:

```
const state = {
    // movie details reducer handles this part:
    movies: {
        "movie1Id": {
            "name": "Title of movie1"
            // more movie details here
        },
        "movie2Id": {
            "name": "Title of movie2"
            // more movie details here
        },
    },

    // cart reducer handles this part:
    cart: {
        "movie1Id": 3, // quantity. user chose 3 tickets for movie1.
        "movie2Id": 1, // quantity. user chose 1 ticket for movie2.
    }
};

const setCartItemAction = (movieId, quantity) => ({
    type: "SET_CART_ITEM",
    payload: { movieId, quantity }
});
```

The `setCartItemAction` would be enough to model your use case. Calling it with a quantity of `0` for a certain movie would be the same as removing the movie from the cart.